# Authorization bearer token in postman

Tags: postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

Im trying to automate postman tests with [Newman](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman/). There is an issue with authorization. The authorization `bearer token` changes and it is dynamic. Does anyone know how to automate this?

Comment: Do you get the token in one of the requests?

Comment: I think so but Im not  completely sure.is there a way to automatically fetch it if its part of get status?

Comment: If it’s a single request that gets the token, it can be it’s own request in the collection or added as a pre request script maybe. You can set the value as a global or environment variable to reuse in other requests.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know if this works.

Answer (score 3):

Postman has this nice feature of variables.
You can read more about them here:
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/environments_and_globals/variables

You can store the bearer token in a variable and update it periodically as per your requirement.

[image: Using global variable]

You can modify this token in the pre-request script / tests script as per your needs.

For eg:

```
let token = pm.globals.get('dynamic_token');
token = 'newModifiedToken90332'; // Perform some operations here.. 

pm.globals.set('dynamic_token', token);
```

[image: Pre-request script]

You can export the collection and globals into Newman and use them.

From [Newman documentation](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman/) you could do the following:

```
$ newman run mycollection.json -e dev_environment.json
```

-e is for using **environment variables** in which you can store your bearer token
Recall that you can export your collection and your environment variables as well.